# How to use cpu-feature in a native library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, cpu

We recently added cpu-features to detect platform features like ARMV8 and CRC, AES and SHA. We caught a [bug report](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/491) for building against the latest NDK. When we attempt to include `<cpu-features.h>` in an `armeabi` project it results in:

```
$ make -f GNUmakefile-cross
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pipe -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -mthumb -msoft-float
-funwind-tables -fexceptions -frtti -DANDROID --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
-Wa,--noexecstack -I/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
-I/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include -c cpu.cpp
In file included from cpu.cpp:26:0:
/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/cpu-features.h:52:6: error:
 #    error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
      ^
cpu.cpp: In function 'bool CryptoPP::CPU_QueryNEON()':
cpu.cpp:402:29: error: 'android_getCpuFeatures' was not declared in this scope
  if (android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON)
                             ^
cpu.cpp:402:33: error: 'ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON' was not declared in this scope
  if (android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON)
                                 ^
make: *** [cpu.o] Error 1
```

The `CXXFLAGS` we are using come directly from a JNI project I created a few years ago. I used `ndk-build` to examine the flags Android's build system sets, and then transferred them to our script. We are not making them up; they are official NDK compiler options.

When I `cat` the header `cpu-features.h` I see an ominous sign:

```
/* __ARM_ARCH__ is a number corresponding to the ARM revision
 * we're going to support. Our toolchain doesn't define __ARM_ARCH__
 * so try to guess it.
 */
#ifndef __ARM_ARCH__
#  if defined __ARM_ARCH_7__   || defined __ARM_ARCH_7A__ || \
        defined __ARM_ARCH_7R__  || defined __ARM_ARCH_7M__
#    define __ARM_ARCH__ 7
#  elif defined __ARM_ARCH_6__   || defined __ARM_ARCH_6J__ || \
        defined __ARM_ARCH_6K__  || defined __ARM_ARCH_6Z__ || \
        defined __ARM_ARCH_6KZ__ || defined __ARM_ARCH_6T2__
#    define __ARM_ARCH__ 6
#  else
#    error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
#  endif
#endif
```

We seem to be missing something in our process and implementation. First, all the definitions needed are provided by the preprocessor (see below). The preprocessor provides `__ARM_ARCH`, but Android's header checks for `__ARM_ARCH__`.

Second, `<machine/cpu-features.h>` does not seem to include needed declarations:

```
$ cat /opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/cpu-features.h | grep -i android_getCpuFeatures
$
```

We don't use Android's build system, so very little of this applies: [The cpufeatures Library](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-features.html). Its also too high level and lacks some of the details we need.

My question is, how do we use cpu-features in a regular native library? What are we missing for the first and second problems?

---

Our script sets `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, etc. They are available for use once the script is sourced. In this case:

```
$ echo $CXX
arm-linux-androideabi-g++
```

And:

```
$ $CXX -dM -E - </dev/null | sort
#define __ACCUM_EPSILON__ 0x1P-15K
#define __ACCUM_FBIT__ 15
#define __ACCUM_IBIT__ 16
#define __ACCUM_MAX__ 0X7FFFFFFFP-15K
#define __ACCUM_MIN__ (-0X1P15K-0X1P15K)
#define __ANDROID__ 1
#define __APCS_32__ 1
#define __arm__ 1
#define __ARM_32BIT_STATE 1
#define __ARM_ARCH 5
#define __ARM_ARCH_5TE__ 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_ARM 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_THUMB 1
#define __ARM_EABI__ 1
#define __ARMEL__ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_CLZ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_DSP 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_QBIT 1
#define __ARM_FP 12
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 4
#define __ARM_PCS 1
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_MINIMAL_ENUM 4
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
#define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __ATOMIC_CONSUME 1
#define __ATOMIC_RELAXED 0
#define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3
#define __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST 5
#define __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ 8
#define __BYTE_ORDER__ __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
...
```

---

None of the cpu-features seem to be declared or defined:

```
$ echo $AOSP_SYSROOT
/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
$ grep -IR android_getCpuFeatures $AOSP_SYSROOT
$ grep -IR ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON $AOSP_SYSROOT
$
```

Comment: Now open in the AOSP Tracker: [Issue 65641866, Dirty compile when compiling cpu-feature.c with C++ compiler](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65641866).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library isn't prebuilt as part of the NDK, but is shipped as source. When building with `ndk-build`, this library can be built automatically by referencing it, but when using an external build system, you need to make sure to include and build it yourself.

The source is in `android-ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures`, and there you'll find a different `cpu-features.h`. (In order to reach the one you found, you probably included `machine/cpu-features.h` instead, which is a completely diffrent thing.)

So you need to include `cpu-features.h` from `android-ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures` and build `cpu-features.c` as part of your build process. Or if you're producing a static library, it can also be enough to build your code against this header, and document that the user of the library needs to include the `cpufeatures` library when producing the final shared library.

Comment: Thanks @mstorsjo. Any ideas about the incorrect use of defines? Do we need to define something due to Android's use of the wrong preprocessor macros?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. The header you accidentally tried to include isn't something that you're supposed to include in any case.

Comment: We are catching more related bugs due to Android's f::k'd up directory layouts and location of source files. I wish they would pull their head out of their a$$ and use `--sysroot` they way it has been used for the  last 20 years or so. They need to stop making s::t up as they go along. By the way, we did not accidentally include anything. Everything we do has a reason. The problem here appears to be AOSP leaving a broken `<cpu-features.h>` in SYSROOT or on-path.

Comment: There is no broken `<cpu-features.h>` in SYSROOT, there is one in `<ndk>/platforms/android-XX/arch-XX/usr/include/machine`. When I try to build a dummy cpp file that includes `<cpu-features.h>` with the exact command line you quoted, it doesn't find the other header from `.../usr/include/machine`, so your first task is to figure out what is making it find something from a `machine` subdirectory that it definitely shouldn't be looking in by default.